# UIScrollView's indicator not showing nor is it scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've got a UIScrollView with vertical content that fits Onan iPhone X but on an SE it won't fit, however when running on an SE the vertical indicator isn't showing and I can't scroll the content.

Here's the high level hierarchy:

[image]

The Scroll View has constraints added to align left/right/top/botton with its parent view, also the Content View has its constraints aligned to the left/right/top/bottom of the Scroll View.
(I was following this reference http://www.thomashanning.com/embedding-whole-screen-into-uiscrollview/)

User Interaction is enabled for the View, Scroll View and Content View. The Scroll view has the horizontal indicator disabled but the vertical enabled.
The view controller is embedded in container view which is sized to be the same size as its parent view.

[image]

Any ideas why I can't see the vertical scroll indicator nor can scroll the content?

Answer (score -1):

have you tried give `ContentView` height equalTo `UIScrollView` but setting the priority to 250?

Comment: Tried it - it didn't fix the issue though

Comment: do the last view got the bottom constraint to ContentView bottom?

Comment: "do the last view" do you mean the bottom most view within the Content View? No it doesn't

Comment: you should definitely add it, without it the scrollView doesn't have the real content size. but only the initial content size

Comment: I tried adding it, but then some views above it weren't displaying fully (A UIText view was getting vertically truncated), so I tried lowering the priority but then that results back to the original problem.

Comment: does all the ContentView subviews got height constraint?

Comment: Yes everything has height constraints - there's no warnings in the storyboard about anything missing a constraint.

Comment: can you share constraints then?

Comment: I've got to leave for a few hours, I'll update the question with full constraints later, thanks for you help so far